# Check if a tree is expanded or open (Selenium / Python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation, tree

I am trying to figure out, how Selenium can check if a tree is open / expanded and if it was successful.

For example we have these lines of code and this is the parent (DOM view using the elements panel).
This is the open tree:
[Tree open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKd0L.jpg)

by using the console tab I see this and I think this could be useful... but I don't really know how to get the state with [`opened: true`]

```
li_attr: {id: "j1_1"}
original: {was_excel_sheet: false, item_name: "Profit and Loss", text: "01 
Profit and Loss", mapped: false, initial_order: "01", …}
parent: "#"
parents: ["#"]
state: {loaded: true, opened: true, selected: true, disabled: false}
text: "01 Profit and Loss"
type: "root"
```

Close tree:
[Tree closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nSCw.jpg)

Comment: Hi Gyrospeter. Could you provide the same html you've done above but with it opened and closed. This way we can see what extra classes we have to work with.

Comment: Of course. Look at the edit. Had to upload pictures, otherwise it would be too much code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think we've got it.

I've used beautiful soup - https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/ - which we use to look through the classes of the html.

Once selenium has loaded the page, grab the html and use beautiful soup to turn it into something we can use - a small example of how to do this below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Given that I don't have the html, I've made some small versions that match the images that you've uploaded, below is an open line item known by the class of 'jstree-open'.

```
open = '''
    <div id="tree" class="jstree jstree-1">
        <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children">
            <li class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-open">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    '''

open_soup = BeautifulSoup(open)
```

Using a css selector we can get all the class names of the li:

```
classes_of_open_li = open_soup.select('div#tree ul.jstree-container-ul li')[0].get('class')
print(classes_of_open_li)

out: ['jstree-node', 'jstree-last', 'jstree-open']
```

we can then test to see whether 'jstree-open' is one of the classes:

```
'jstree-open' in classes_of_open_li

out: True
```

We can then test the opposite:

```
closed = '''
    <div id="tree" class="jstree jstree-1">
        <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children">
            <li class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-closed">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    '''
closed_soup = BeautifulSoup(closed)
classes_of_closed_li = closed_soup.select('div#tree ul.jstree-container-ul li')[0].get('class')
'jstree-open' in classes_of_closed_li

out: False
```

After which is you wanted to select all of the list items you can use the same function to return a list of all list items:

```
li = '''
    <div id="tree" class="jstree jstree-1">
        <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children">
            <li class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-closed">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    '''
line_soup = BeautifulSoup(li)
all_line_items = line_soup.select('div#tree ul.jstree-container-ul li ul li')

out: [<li></li>, <li></li>, <li></li>, <li></li>]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Get some weird Errors. Will continue with my next tasks and come back later to that problem.